# Pass values in an array to redshift parameterized query

Tags: amazon-redshift

`let query ='INSERT INTO tablename (id, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)' let params='id, test1, test2, test3,test4, test5';  client.parameterizedQuery(query, params, function (err, result) { if (err) reject(err) else { resolve('INSERTED Batch'); } });`

Its is triggering the query with these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your `params` is a string. But you should pass a list of items.

```js
let params=['id', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];
```